# Google Pages Speed Tool doesn't support AMP pages?

Tags: amp-html, pagespeed

I see recently when testing AMP webpage, page speed tool mark AMP scripts as => remove unused java script while they are already used. and it affect mobile speed badly, please assist
to test:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://www.sawtrax.com/amp/

Comment: I have the same problem. With the new PageSpeed score, AMP is slightly penalized